# DropDownListFor not Working Outside BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP.net MVC 3.

Here is my code:

```
<tr class="print-hide" id="NewExpenseTypeRow">
    <td class="text">Add Expense Type</td>
    <td class="form-values">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)</td>
    <td class="form-values">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.Categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c }))</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateExpenseType", "Grants", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UpdateExpenseType" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Mode)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GrantId)

            <input type="submit" value="Save" data-values="#NewExpenseTypeRow .form-values input" />
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

The value in the DropDownListFor is not making it to the controller even though I'm using class="form-values".  The controller just gets the default value for the field.

How do I get the value in DropDownListFor value into the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can't without javascript intervention.  Standard HTML rules dictate that anything you want posted must be enclosed within the `<form>` element.  That's just plain HTML Posting 101.

Also, `class="form-values"` has nothing to do with form posting (unless used by your javascript framework).

So, just move your BeginForm up...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateExpenseType", "Grants", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UpdateExpenseType" })) {
<tr class="print-hide" id="NewExpenseTypeRow">
  <td class="text">Add Expense Type</td>
  <td class="form-values">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)</td>
  <td class="form-values">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.Categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c }))</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Mode)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GrantId)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" data-values="#NewExpenseTypeRow .form-values input" />
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

That's the basic way of doing it without javascript hacks.

If you want to get nasty, you can use Javascript to hook into the form posting event, capture the data for your elements on you want on the page, add it to the form data variable, and submit it via javascript and finally redirect the page.

That's way more effort than doing what I just suggested above.

### EDIT: Ok, I see this in your submit button:

```
data-values="#NewExpenseTypeRow .form-values input"
```

You must be using some nuget package/javascript/jquery framework that is attempting to wire this up for you automatically, similar to my option 2 above with custom javascript to do this for you.

Don't.  Most likely it is a bug in the javascript you are using (that you don't know you are using) not able to recognize the fields.

Again, don't do that.  I don't know what javascript you are attempting to use, and it is a problem with that javascript/plugin/jquery that is your problem, if you want to continue using javascript.

Don't.

1) Get rid of the `data-values="#NewExpenseTypeRow .form-values input"`

2) Follow my steps above to move the `@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateEx...` up higher to surround the entire form.  It does not hurt anything, and the `<form>` tag is not used for styling.

Less is more my friend.

## Edit 2 - I think this is what you are looking for...

The naming convention of the data-values and form id is making me think you are using some template or larger solution.  Almost like there is some ajax going on.

I think your problem is in whatever javascript code you are using to capture the input fields.

Note that `@Html.DropDownListFor()` generates an `<select>`, not an `<input>` field.  So perhaps you need to change the `data-values` on your submit button to capture `<select>` as well as `<input>`?  Something like this:

```
data-values="#NewExpenseTypeRow .form-values input,#NewExpenseTypeRow .form-values select"
```

I am taking a guess that your javascript framework you are using uses this `data-values`  attribute as the jquery selector(s) to grab data from.  Which, you can combine multiple in jquery selectors with a comma.  So, that may work.

That's only a guess though without knowing what javascript you are using to grab that data-values attribute and how it is being used.

Comment: Do you think the difference could be in EditorFor vs DropDownListFor?

Comment: Edited answer...  You are using a javascript framework and should be asking a question for that javascript code and/or framework instead.  your question here is how to get ASP.NET MVC to submit the form values, and my answer resolved that by placing the `form` tag properly at the top, surrounding the fields you are submitting.  If you want to fix the javascript code you have for the `submit` button, I think you need to make a new question with that javascript code and/or library.

Comment: ok, i think i figured out your problem.  see Edit 2.  note, that's as far as we can go without you editing your original question and listing what javascript framework you are using (or MVC template and its nuget packages/javascript framework) to perform this ajax.